# Ruby / Resque / Redis: How to set up workers on different machines?

Tags: ruby, redis, sinatra, resque

I've been looking into resque for distributed background jobs.
I managed to get everything working on one machine through the demo app. But I don't know how to set everything up so the workers run on different machines. I read that it's just necessary that the workers have a connection to the redis server. But I still have no idea where to start.
Is there a step-by-step instruction somewhere? I didn't find any documentation about this.

Or can someone please explain it to me?

I don't use rails btw, I'm using Sinatra.

Thx

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are correct If all your worker can access the redis you can hook them up to  distribute them on different machine

For that you need worker to be connected to redis (I assume are available to all worker)

Now in Resque to connect to that remote redis all it has to do is like this

`Resque.redis = "redis://[your host]:[your port]"`

you can also see the same it mention over [here](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/blob/master/lib/resque.rb#L37-L39)

Perhaps define it in your `config/application.rb`

Hope this help

Comment: Okay, and is it necessary to mantain a copy of all the application code throughout all machines?

Comment: @Mexxer Yes perhaps you need to copy application code through out all machine because `resque` is like triggered by rake task and rake task are like application specific but ,may I know what are trying to achieve perhaps like what is ur end result GOAL . because your comment above make me believe you intending to use resque as kind of messaging thing between different application correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is: I want my webapp to send jobs to the redis server and have a cluster of multiple machines where the workers run and execute the jobs (for example: send emails).

Comment: @Mexxer Any progress on that? Thanx in advance!

Comment: @hackhowtofaq progress on what ?

Comment: @Viren On setting up the webapp in such a way that multiple remote PCs are executing the jobs.

Answer (score 0):

The Redis security guide suggests that it is unsafe to expose your Redis server to the public internet.  So, your safest bet is probably to create an SSH tunnel from each worker machine to the Redis server.  You can find instructions here:

https://briandamaged.org/blog/?p=1675

Once you have secured your Redis server and established an SSH tunnel, your workers can connect to the server by accessing a port on localhost.  For instance:

```
# Port 2000 is a tunnel to the Redis server
Resque.redis = "redis://localhost:2000"
```